# Which field of theoretical physics is most promising?

Tags: soft-question

I'm about to choose university and I really love physics, but I don't know about use of it. What field is most promising to study? Where could I work with subatomic particles PhD? Or maybe nuclear physics? I know about CERN and supercollider in Geneva, but what are the odds of getting there? I'm afraid I could just go sell in supermarket with this. So what do you think?

Comment: Note that most universities don't require that you choose a subfield *before* enrolling. Instead, if you choose to start studying physics, then you will usually study introductory courses to various subfields of physics during your first 2-3 years (classical mechanics, electromagnetism, thermal physics, fluid mechanics, quantum mechanics, relativity, solid state physics, etc), and then choose a specialization after those years.

Comment: Also, note that most people working at the supercollider in Geneva are not considered *theoretical physicists* but *experimental physicists*.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. So, you have probably bigger odds as experimental physicist than theoretical unless you're genius? I live in europe so there are not much research institues like Caltech in California.

Comment: If you are going to make a living as a theorist you will have to be *very* good. So good that your undergrad course seems simple and hardly takes any effort at all.